# Ingest pipeline is not working over logs obtained from an event hub wih filebeat

Tags: kibana, pipeline, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, filebeat

I am sending logs to an azure eventhub with Serilog (using `WriteTo.AzureEventHub(eventHubClient)`), after that I am running a filebeat process with the azure module enabled, so I send these logs to elasticsearch to be able to explore them with Kibana.

The problem I have is that all the information goes to the field "message", I would need to separate the information of my logs in different fields to be able to do good queries.

The way I found was create an ingest pipeline in Kibana and through a grok processor I separate the fields inside the "meessage" and generate multiple fields. In the filebeat.yml I set the pipeline name, but nothing happen, it seems the pipeline is not working.

```
output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
  pipeline: "filebeat-otc"
```

Does anybody knows what I am missing? THANKS in advance.

EDITION. I will add an example of my pipeline and my data. In the simulation is working properly:

```
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline": {
    "processors": [
      {
        "grok": {
          "field": "message",
          "patterns": [
            "%{TIME:timestamp}\\s%{LOGLEVEL}\\s{[a-zA-Z]*:%{UUID:CorrelationID},[a-zA-Z]*:%{TEXT:OperationTittle},[a-zA-Z]*:%{TEXT:OriginSystemName},[a-zA-Z]*:%{TEXT:TargetSystemName},[a-zA-Z]*:%{TEXT:OperationProcess},[a-zA-Z]*:%{TEXT:LogMessage},[a-zA-Z]*:%{TEXT:ErrorMessage}}"
          ],
          "pattern_definitions": {
            "LOGLEVEL" : "\\[[^\\]]*\\]",
            "TEXT" : "[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "message": "15:13:59 [INF] {CorrelationId:83355884-a351-4c8b-af8d-b77c48462f36,OperationTittle:Operation1,OriginSystemName:Fexa,TargetSystemName:Usina,OperationProcess:Testing Log Data,LogMessage:Esto es una buena prueba,ErrorMessage:null}"
      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "message": "20:13:48 [INF] {CorrelationId:8451ee54-efca-40be-91c8-8c8e18e33f58,OperationTittle:null,OriginSystemName:Fexa,TargetSystemName:Donna,OperationProcess:Testing Log Data,LogMessage:null,ErrorMessage:null}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with an example of your message and the ingest pipeline you are using. When you simulate the ingest pipeline it works ok? Are you using any filebeat module?

Comment: @leandrojmp, Yes I am using an azure filebeat module. And yes, when I simulate the ingest pipeline it works ok. I will add an example as you asked. Thanks!

Comment: If I'm not wrong, when you use a module it will create and use an ingest pipeline in elasticsearch, and the `pipeline` option in the output is ignored. You would need to edit that pipeline or use the [`index.final_pipeline`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html#set-final-pipeline) setting in your index. You can check it in Kibana going to Stack Management / Ingest Node Pipelines.

Comment: @leandrojmp do you have idea how can I know what is the pipeline my module is using? it should be specified in any config yml file I guess, but I am not finding it. Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: Do you have Kibana? It is easier to edit there, go to Stack Management / Ingest Node Pipelines. I would recommend that you use the `index.final_pipeline` setting and add your ingest pipeline, it will then be processed after the module pipeline.

Comment: @leandrojmp as you suggested I set the index.final_pipeline with my pipeline and "IT WORKS!!" THANKS!! I spent a lot of time trying to do it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems when you use a module it will create and use an ingest pipeline in elasticsearch, and the pipeline option in the output is ignored.
So my solution was modify the `index.final_pipeline`. For this, in Kibana I went to   **Stack Management / Index Management** there I found my index, there I went to Edit Settings and set `"index.final_pipeline": "the-name-of-my-pipeline"`.
I hope this helps to anybody.

This was thanks to [leandrojmp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1123206/leandrojmp)

Comment: I am not how about your setup works. Usually, there are either rollover indices or daily indices. And these changes are done in template so that upcoming index will also have the same settings. For the already existing index, we need to do it the way you described.